ERC20 test with chai issue
I am starting my journy with contracts and decided to begin with some ERC20. I used some ready examples but can't get pass one single error.
To state my knowlede level. I am C++ big data programmer. Never have I ever use sol or chai and I only know JS a littile bit. So feel free to domionate me with your knowledge. Any usefull directions where to start are also welcome!
So the issue!
Here is my test code:
it("Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens", async function () {
    const initialOwnerBalance = await BitCoinV20.balanceOf(owner.address);
    // Try to send 1 token from addr1 (0 tokens) to owner (1000000 tokens).
    // `require` will evaluate false and revert the transaction.
    await expect(
        await BitCoinV20.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address, 1)
    ).to.be.revertedWith("ERC20InsufficientBalance(\"" + addr1 + "\", 0, 1)"); //ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

    // Owner balance shouldn't have changed.
    expect(await BitCoinV20.balanceOf(owner.address)).to.equal(
    initialOwnerBalance
    );
});

Here is setup for it:
beforeEach(async function () {
    // Get the ContractFactry and Signers here.
    Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("BitCoinV20");
    [owner, addr1, addr2] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

    BitCoinV20 = await Token.deploy(tokenCap, tokenBlockReward);
});

And the error I get:
 1) BitCoinV20 contract
       Transactions
         Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'ERC20InsufficientBalance("0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8", 0, 1)'
    at BitCoinV20._update (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:195)
    at BitCoinV20._update (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol:46)
    at BitCoinV20._update (contracts/BitCoinV20.sol:21)
    at BitCoinV20._transfer (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:178)
    at BitCoinV20.transfer (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:111)
    at EdrProviderWrapper.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:446:41)
    at HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:125:18)
    at send (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:313:20)
    at Proxy.transfer (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:352:16)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\BitCoinV20.js:62:17)

Let me know what do I do wrong?

The Error you are trying to catch is a custom error, but the way you have written the test is for require or revert error message strings.
This is the correct way to handle custom errors in hardhat:
 await expect(BitCoinV20.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address,1)).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(
  BitCoinV20,
  "ERC20InsufficientBalance"
).withArgs(addr1, 0, 1);


Refer to this doc for more explanation.

I gave you best naswer but there is one more think to be fixed in it. Remove await that is after expect.

Thanks, I just focused on the Error part and didn't notice the rest of the line.
